# C++ template function from outside class

Tags: c++, class, templates, struct

I'm writing a program for the Arduino platform using platformio and have some data nested into structs along these lines, that resides in a class header file (gauge.h)

```
#include "Arduino.h"

class gaugeClass{
  public:
    template<typename T, typename S>
    void writeFlash( const T& dataParam, const S datVal);
    void writeThreshold( int16_t datVal );

    struct Flasht{
      struct Settingst{
        struct UnderVoltaget{
          struct Thresholdt{
            int16_t val = 2850;
            uint16_t addr = 0x4481;
          } threshold;
          struct Delayt{
            uint8_t val = 2;
            uint16_t addr = 0x4483;
          } delay;
        } underVoltage;
      } settings;
    } ;

  private:
};
```

In gauge.cpp, I have a template function to access the values.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "gauge.h"

template<typename T, typename S>
void gaugeClass::writeFlash( const T& dataParam, const S datVal){
  byte addrByte2 = dataParam.addr >> 8;
  Serial.println( addrByte2, HEX );
  Serial.println( datVal );
}

void gaugeClass::writeThreshold( int16_t datVal ){
  Flasht flash;
  writeFlash( flash.settings.underVoltage.threshold, datVal );
}
```

Then my main.cpp program as is follows

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <gauge.h>

gaugeClass myGauge;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  gaugeClass::Flasht flash;
  myGauge.writeThreshold( flash.settings.underVoltage.threshold.val );
}

void loop(){
}
```

But I want to be able to call the template parameter directly from my main program like

```
myGauge.writeFlash( flash.settings.underVoltage.threshold, flash.settings.underVoltage.threshold.val );
```

When I add this instead of the `writeThreshold` function, the compiler is giving undefined reference error.
How can I call the function differently?
Thanks

Comment: Variable cannot be named `class`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the error message you get

Comment: In `main()` change `class` to `Flash` in the statement that calls the member function `writeThreshold()`.    Also, `main()` returns `int`, not `void`.

Comment: offtopic: having variable names and type names both starting with a capital letter makes the code hard to read, especially when the names differ only by a single letter. A common convention is capital for your types and small letter for variables. It doesnt matter that much what convention you use as long as you are consistent

Comment: sorry, had tried to abstract it down. I have the contents of 3 files needed now. I can reproduce the issue with them. I've acted on the naming recommendations. Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is that you defined the template function in the .cpp file, rather than the header file. See e.g. [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vR69XmhDjYFiVh3t) MRE vs. a "functioning" [one](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1NmqeBtxQaKGsjwM).

Comment: Amazing, thanks @Bob__, that works perfectly. I'm just dipping my toes into using templates. Appreciate the help.